# Find Digit and Append Number Word to String Using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to find any digits an input string and then append the English word for each digit at the end of the string. 
However, my code is throwing an error `can't assign to function call`.

```
import re

def to_eng(s):

    words = {"0":"zero","1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight","9":"nine"}
    k = re.findall(r"[0-9]",s)
    for i in k:
        w = words.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]
    print(s + w)

s = "I want to buy 17 cars."
to_eng(s)
```

I would like my output to be: `I want to buy 17 cars. one seven`

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there's missing something here (maybe a function call?)

```
for i in k:
    w = words.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]
    #  ^                                 ^
print(s + w)
```

But you could change it to:

```
def to_eng(s):
    words = {"0":"zero","1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight","9":"nine"}
    rx = re.compile(r'\d')
    for m in rx.finditer(s):
        s = s + " " + words[m.group(0)]
    print(s)
```

Yielding

```
I want to buy 17 cars. one seven
```

---

Or - even better - use a list altogether:

```
def to_eng(s):
    words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
    rx = re.compile(r'\d')

    return s + " ".join(words[int(m.group(0))] for m in rx.finditer(s))
```

---

As for your last question - inserting brackets with the english words - you need to make up a replacement function:

```
def to_eng(s):
    words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
    rx = re.compile(r'\d+')

    def repl(digits):
        return digits.group(0) + " (" + " ".join(words[int(x)] for x in digits.group(0)) + ")"

    return rx.sub(repl, s)
```

This yields for your example string:

```
I want to buy 17 (one seven) cars.
```

Comment: @whiteyflowr: See the updated answer at the bottom (and accept an answer if it helped you).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way:

```
import re
s = "I want to buy 17 cars."
words = {"0":"zero","1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight","9":"nine"}
k = re.findall(r"[0-9]",s)
w = ' '.join([words[i] for i in k])
print(w) #one seven
```

This solution use so called `list` comprehension, this allow more concise code than using `for` loop.